# How to keep reply window as a new window in Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook

I have opened a new window using:

```
Inspector insp = ((MailItem)Response).GetInspector;
((_Inspector)insp).Activate();
```

for reply.

But the focus to the new window is lost and shows the Outlook main window, the reply content is displayed in outlook main window and also in the new window I opened using `Activate()`.

How can I get focus to the new window opened?

Answer (score 0):

Use `((MailItem)Response).Display()`